# Why is bootstrap not aligning cells correctly?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to use Bootstrap, and having an issue that in medium resolution two columns that should be side-by-side, are displaying underneath each other, see screenshot http://dynanetics.com/problem-screenshot.png, the code is at http://dynanetics.com

At higher resolutions (large and xlarge) this works correctly. Why is this happening at medium resolution?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

The relevant code is below:

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">                      

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 d-block float-left">
                            <img src="logo-sitesmall.png" class="d-block float-none">                              
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 d-block float-left text-center">
                            <h1 class="brandname">Test site name</h1>                              
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">                      
</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't think you need `d-block float-left`

Comment: what resolution are you getting this at?

Comment: enlarge you div fro 4  to 8

Comment: I moved it from 4 to 8, remove the tags, and at 700 px resolution on browser, uploaded the changes, and still happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think your div="col-md-4", after first row div is too small for both the content to be on same line in medium resolution, try to increase it.

Comment: I set everything to 6 units in size, uploaded and still happens. I appreciate the suggestion, I just don't understand why the row is breaking the way it is...